# How do e-mail relays detect who clicked "Report Junk" or "Report as Spam" on an e-mail?

Tags: email, spam

How does an e-mail relay service (like [Campaign Monitor](https://campaignmonitor.com)) discover which of my recipients clicked "Report Junk" or "Spam" on a campaign e-mail (as they surface this in a dashboard back in the client)? Are e-mail providers providing endpoints to companies such as Campaign Monitor in order for them receive such information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, email providers offer a way to acquire such information. It's called a [feedback loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_loop_(email)). The exact implementation depends on a particular email service with some of them using a standard Abuse Reporting Format reports and some having their own solutions.

It's unclear which providers send the user's email address to the campaign originator, as Wikipedia notes:

> The majority of ESP offering Feedback Loop do not include in the report the email address of the recipient, who marked the message.

More info on feedback loops with details of particular implementations is available at [www.emailfeedbackloops.com](https://www.emailfeedbackloops.com).

---

Campaign Monitor is clear about them [using the feature](https://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=795):

> Through a direct feedback loop (FBL) with major ISPs, like AOL, Yahoo! and Hotmail, our system can automatically detect if a significant number of your recipients flag your emails as spam.

An important note from the article is that in case of several email providers, clicking the "Spam" button triggers an automatic unsubscribe action which identifies an individual user. At the same time Gmail does not perform this action automatically.

In case of Gmail the data is statistical and doesn't identify individual users and their actions, so at least Google's feedback doesn't allow to tell "*which of [the] recipients clicked [Spam]*".

Comment: Great resource! This cleared things up for me, thank-you.